# Does anyone know how i can edit ggMarginal to show density lines here

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add density lines around my scatterplot. Does anyone know how to edit this code to make it work? something to do with the 'p' argument i think

```
 scatter4 = ggplot(mammal, aes(x = gestation, y = dream)) +
   geom_point(colour = 'red') +
   ggMarginal(p, type = "densigram") +
   xlab("Gestation (in days)") +
   ylab("Dreaming sleep (in hrs/day)")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ggMarginal` is a function that modifies an existing ggplot object. You cannot add it to an existing plot with the `+` operator.

First create your plot with its labels, etc, and store it to a variable. Then pass this variable as the first argument to `ggMarginal`

```r
library(tourr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggExtra)

scatter4 = ggplot(mammal, aes(x = gestation, y = dream)) +
   geom_point(colour = 'red') +
   xlab("Gestation (in days)") +
   ylab("Dreaming sleep (in hrs/day)") 
 
ggMarginal(scatter4, type = "densigram")
```

[image]

---

**Data**

```r
mammal <- openintro::mammals
names(mammal)[5] <- "dream"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>